# PHP - Show the date with hours, minutes and seconds set to zero

Tags: php, date, format

I need a DateTime object that sets hours, minutes and seconds to '00:00:00'

Why does the following still output '20:53:19' instead of '00:00:00'?

```
const DATETIME_TO_MYSQL_DATETIME = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
const DATE_FORMAT = 'j.n.Y';
    $this->today = DateTime::createFromFormat(self::DATE_FORMAT, (new DateTime())->format(self::DATE_FORMAT));
   die($this->today->format(self::DATETIME_TO_MYSQL_DATETIME));
```

Output:
`2013-12-02 20:53:19`

Comment: Why do you care about what the time says, if all you ever need is the date?

Comment: Why not just get rid of the time section of the `DATETIME_TOMYSQL_DATETIME` format..?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i need that DateTime object for mysql query, but hours, minutes etc. must be 0

Comment: The query will probably assume its zero if you leave hours and mins off entirely

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
const DATETIME_TO_MYSQL_DATETIME = 'Y-m-d 00:00:00';
```

if you want the hours/minutes/seconds to be `00:00:00`, regardless of time.

Comment: yes that is what i want, i didn't know about this, thx. But anyway why that my code doesn't work how i am expecting?

Comment: @Krab What do you mean? You were passing in `'Y-m-d H:i:s';` H:i:s = Hours:Minutes:Seconds.

Comment: yes but that DateTime object shouldn't contains info about hours etc. because i created it only with year, month and day, so it should return 00:00:00 i think

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
$this->today = new DateTime('today');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const DATETIME_TO_MYSQL_DATETIME = 'Y-m-d 00:00:00'
```

No minutes, hours or seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's outputting the hours, minutes and seconds is because you are specifying the format of the date. Removing "H:i:s" from the "Y-m-d H:i:s" should remove the time stamp. Replacing "H:i:s" with "00:00:00" will set the time stamp.

You can take a look at the PHP [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for more formats.

Example:

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d'));
// string(10) "2013-12-02"

$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
echo $current_date;
// 2013-12-02
```